# Running geoserver behind nginx from custom location

Tags: geoserver, proxy, tomcat

I was required to make GeoServer to be accessible from `/beta/geoserver` however I always get redirected back to `/geoserver` which is 404 of course.

Here is the current location rule:

```
location /beta/geoserver/ {
   proxy_set_header Host               $host:$server_port;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/geoserver/; 
}
```

And my observations:

`/beta/geoserver/` redirects to `/geoserver/web/` which is 404

`/beta/geoserver/index.html` redirects to `/beta/geoserver/web/` which is fine.

I can try login there but I'm immediately redirected to `/geoserver/web;jsessionid=...` which is 404 again and I'm stuck.

The only thing I've configured is the *Proxy Base URL* but that's used by the services but not by the GeoServer AFAIK.

*I'm neither a Tomcat nor a GeoServer expert so I guess the solution is one configuration file away from me but I haven't found a single clue of how to solve it.*

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this (Also BOO to whoever closed this. Its *CLEARLY* a GIS related question.)

Comment: I never got a solution to this. Soon I left the whole gis industry.

Comment: I did get it going in the end, but hoo boy was it a mess of *stuff* being tried. I think you need to set the proxy url thingo in the settings so that when it constructs hard URLs it knows what to do.